# To what extent are supplementary yum repositories certified by CentoOS?

Tags: certificates, centos

I'm building something which uses libsodium and will run on Ubuntu and CentOS 7.

Ubunutu has the `libsodium-dev` package, but CentOS doesn't seem to include it by default.

I see [instructions](http://www.servermom.org/how-to-enable-remi-repo-on-centos-7-6-and-5/2790/) to use the REMI repository and then `yum --enablerepo=remi install foo`

As I understand it, repository contents are cryptographically signed with root verification keys distributed with the OS. Are supplementary repositories used in this fashion certified by CentOS as trustworthy? Or by downloading and installing the repository rpm am I affirming to the system that *I* trust this new repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed a fresh CentOS last Friday, so I do have a decent machine to test this.  And yes, there is a more-or-less consistent chain of trust.

`libsodium` is in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repositories.  It is part of the REMI repository alright, yet REMI is one of the repositories that is pretty much completely included in EPEL.  And, if you are already using an RPM repository outside of the base/extras/updates repositories that come with CentOS by default you probably should be using EPEL.

EPEL is maintained by the Fedora project and therefore it is part of RedHat in a way (the Fedora project is part of RedHat).  This also means that RedHat EL includes a signed RPM package (called `epel-release`, so `yum install epel-release` checks it out) that (among a couple of other changes) will install the PKI key in `/etc/pki/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7`.  And the `libsodium` package in the EPEL repo is singed with that key.

**Warning:** EPEL packages are checked in a best effort manner.  And, since these packages evolve much faster than the base/extras/updates repos, they may present higher risk.  In other words, EPEL has a better chain of trust than taking packages directly from REMI, yet, if you are paranoid, you should not use extra repositories at all.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is a operating system. It can't certify anything.

If you are asking if the packages are cryptographically verified with a key that is part of CentOS: yes. The public key for this repository is part of a current CentOS installation

If you are asking if anyone will guarantee you that the packages in the repository fulfill any requirements you might have: no, no one does that

But you are using CentOS. No one guarantees you anything for your operating system anyway. If you need any legal security, you have to pay for a support contract. What exactly is guaranteed depends on your contract.

Comment: I'm not talking about legal guarantees, only technical ones. By "certified as trustworthy" I mean "signed by the same chain of trust as the main repository". From a practical point of view, if I fetch altered data from CentOS repos, the signatures will fail. Will the same test capture altered REMI data, or does installing REMI consist of saying "here is a new key which I trust"?

Comment: This depends on exactly which REMI repo you use and which CentOS version you have installed. Let's say you install the package http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm then this package includes the gpg key used to sign packages in the repo. So you tell the package manager that you trust this new key!